# Task.Factory.StartNew vs new Task

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous

Does anyone know if there is any difference between doing `Task.Factory.StartNew` vs `new Task` followed by calling `Start` on the task. Looking at reflector there doesn't seem to be much difference. So perhaps the only difference is that `Task.Factory.StartNew`returns a task that is already started. Is this correct?

I know that `Task.Factory.StartNew`and `Task.Run` have different default options and `Task.Run` is the preferred option for .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx) great article by Stephen Toub, which explains that there is actually a performance penalty when using `new Task(...).Start()`, as the start method needs to use synchronization to make sure the task is only scheduled once.

His advice is to prefer using `Task.Factory.StartNew` for .net 4.0. For .net 4.5 `Task.Run` is [the better option](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Comment: Sometimes (rarely) you may need to use `Task` constructor, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21424084/1768303

Comment: More confirmation of preference to `Task.Run` by @StephenCleary [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: Updated link for someone who wants to read the article - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/

Answer (score 17):

Actually in [the article by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) he specifies that Task.Run() is exactly equivalent to using Task.Factory.StartNew() with the default parameters:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, 
CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: Not exactly equivalent when it comes to async. As Stephen Toub explains.  [This has tripped me up before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task)