# Task cancellation from inside the task body

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I read about the Cancellation methods but based on my understanding they all provide control over tasks from outside the task, but if i want to cancel a task from the inside.

For example in this pseudo code:

```
Task tasks = new Task(() =>
{ 
     bool exists = CheckFromDB();
      if (!exists)
         break;
}
```

Can i cancel a task from the inside? 
The only idea i got is to trigger an exception inside the task and handle it from outside but surly that is not the way to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to truly Cancel the task (e.g. after it's completed the [`Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status(v=vs.110).aspx) property would be set to `Canceled`), you can do it this way:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;

Task innerCancel = new Task(
    () =>
    {
        if (!CheckFromDB())
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    },
    token);
```

When you use `return` task won't be actually *canceled*, but rather code after the `return` statement won't be executed, and the task itself will have its state as `RanToCompletion`.

---

On a side note it's [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087005/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task) to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` for .NET 4 and `Task.Run` for .NET 4.5 instead of constructor to create tasks.

Comment: This is a far better way to do it.

Comment: You should use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task` to return a hot task rather than a cold one

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I agree with using `Task.Run` instead of returning a cold task, but in this case I've decided to follow up the way OP wrote it for the sake of consistency.

Comment: I think you should show the OP the right path instead of sticking with an incorrect consistency :)

Comment: Note if you have no need to cancel outside of the Task you can also drop the cancelation token and do `throw new OperationCanceledException()` in the place of `cts.Cancel()` to get a similar effect.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda expression code inside a task behaves just the same as in any other method. If you want to end the task for some reason you can just simply return:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{ 
    if(!CheckFromDB())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

You can also throw an exception. That will end the task and mark it as faulted but there's no reason to do so if you can avoid it. If you are really responding to some problem that you can't overcome, then yes, just throw an exception.

Comment: Isn't there an property i can use or assign so that i can handle the return.

Comment: @user733659 To know that a specific return was made? not really... You can however make the lambda return a value (a boolean maybe). You could also throw a specific exception.

Comment: You can use events or a http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx