# Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I just saw 3 routines regarding TPL usage which do the same job; here is the code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";

    // Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression. 
    Task taskA = new Task( () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
    // Start the task.
    taskA.Start();

    // Output a message from the calling thread.
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread '{0}'.", 
                  Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    taskA.Wait();
}

public static void Main()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";

    // Define and run the task.
    Task taskA = Task.Run( () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));

    // Output a message from the calling thread.
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread '{0}'.", 
                      Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    taskA.Wait();
}

public static void Main()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";

    // Better: Create and start the task in one operation. 
    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));

    // Output a message from the calling thread.
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread '{0}'.", 
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

    taskA.Wait();                  
}
```

I just do not understand why MS gives 3 different ways to run jobs in TPL because they all work the same: `Task.Start()`, `Task.Run()` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Tell me, are `Task.Start()`, `Task.Run()` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()` all used for the same purpose or do they have different significance?

When should one use `Task.Start()`, when should one use `Task.Run()` and when should one use `Task.Factory.StartNew()`?

Please help me to understand their real usage as per scenario in great detail with examples, thanks.

Comment: there is an [old article explaining that here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx) and [here for the newer `Task.Run`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) - maybe this will answer your question ;)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21427264/1768303) is an example of where `Task.Start` is actually useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Answer (score 222, accepted):

`Task.Run` is a shorthand for `Task.Factory.StartNew` with specific safe arguments:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    action, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

It was added in .Net 4.5 to help with the increasingly frequent usage of `async` and offloading work to the `ThreadPool`.

`Task.Factory.StartNew` (added with TPL in .Net 4.0) is much more robust. You should only use it if `Task.Run` isn't enough, for example when you want to use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` (though it's unnecessary when the delegate is async. More on that on my blog: [LongRunning Is Useless For Task.Run With async-await](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/)). More on `Task.Factory.StartNew` in [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Don't ever create a `Task` and call `Start()` unless you find an extremely good reason to do so. It should only be used if you have some part that needs to create tasks but not schedule them and another part that schedules without creating. That's almost never an appropriate solution and could be dangerous. More in ["Task.Factory.StartNew" vs "new Task(...).Start"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/)

In conclusion, mostly use `Task.Run`, use `Task.Factory.StartNew` if you must and never use `Start`.

Comment: u said "Don't ever create a Task and call Start()" redirect me to any good write up which will show that may causes by Task.Start(). i need details because u r saying to avoid it. thanks for reply.

Comment: r u talking about this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx ??

Comment: @Mou indeed. specifically the big paragraph at the beginning.

Comment: @Mou `Task.Start` has its place for inheriting types mostly.

Comment: it would be very nice if you pin point and discuss the problem of Task.Start() with example code. thanks

Comment: @Mou It's inefficient as it requires synchronization to make sure it's only called once. The other options do not.

Comment: @ i3arnon : i am not being able to visualize the issue u said " It's inefficient as it requires synchronization to make sure it's only called once" can u plzz discuss this issue with easy sample code to understand the root of the problem. thanks

Comment: @Mou You should probably read the post that explains this issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx

Comment: The synchronization cost should be negligible. Locks are expensive only when contested.

Answer (score 19):

**Short answer**:

If you are not using *nested children's tasks* and always want your tasks to be executed on *Thread Pool* it is better to use `Task.Run`.

**Long answer:**

`Task.Run` and  `Task.Factory.StartNew` both provides support for creating and scheduling Task objects so we don't need to create a `Task` and call `Start()`

```
Task.Run(action);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

And

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Current);
```

`Task.Run` uses `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` which means that children's tasks can not be attached to the parent and it uses `TaskScheduler.Default` which means that the one that runs tasks on Thread Pool will always be used to run tasks.

`Task.Factory.StartNew` uses `TaskScheduler.Current` which means scheduler of the current thread, it might be `TaskScheduler.Default` but not always.