# C# Task class, I was having trouble when using asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that need to call webservice to get data. If each record(total 200) needs to be called once webservice，then it will take a long time(per more than 10 seconds one response). So I use asynchronous to improve efficiency. But I meet a problem. When using the Task, it should call 200 times Webservice, but it only calls more than 100 times lead to incomplete result.

*Hope someone can help me, thank you very much.*

Code:

```
string EffectiveDate = string.Empty;
IList<Task<string>> list = new List<Task<string>>();

foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<string>(() =>
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        string columnId;
        try
        {
            var rates = GetMainRateModel(dr);
            lock (_objMainRatesAsync)
            {
                long seq = _redis.Core.IncrementValue(_currUserKey);
                columnId = dr["ColumnId"].GetString();
                EffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Validity date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                if (rates != null)
                {
                    foreach (var rate in rates)
                    {
                        var surCharges = GetContractSurchargeModel(rate, EffectiveDate);
                        rate.Surcharges = surCharges;
                        GetVATOSSurcharges(rate, surCharges, EffectiveDate, dr);
                    }
                    _redis.Hash_Set(_currRates, columnId, rates);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eex)
        {
            lock (_objProcessRateAsync)
            {
                _sbErrors.AppendLine(string.Format("Error, when the get data from web service. Detail message: {0}", eex.Message));
            }
            result = eex.Message;
        }

        return result;
    }));

    list.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: Your code seems to have multiple threading issues. The main problem is the use of the captured `dr` but I'm not sure if that's the only one.

Comment: just some tips: if the `GetContractSurchargeModel()/GetVATOSSurcharges()` doesn't use any state. try to get the `foreach (var rate in rates)` out of the loop. Also if the `GetContractSurchargeModel()` does a lookup in the database. You should use a db connection each task. You might pass the dbconnection object as parameter.

Comment: If you're not awaiting the results but block until they are done. You should switch to `Parallel.Foreach(....)`  which also solves the _"captured dr"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other said. You have a problem in the method which is running on several threads.

A good habit is to run ONLY static methods on threads. It stops you from using "shared variables" unintentionally between several threads. A good practice is to declare all parameters, which method running on several threads needs - and pass them in "Task.Factory.StartNew" method

One more good tip. Use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew

here is why:  [Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew))

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll try to follow your tips.