# different behavior between Factory.StartNew and Task.Run?

Tags: c#, .net, task, taskscheduler

I'm trying to understand the difference between Factory.StartNew and Task.Run. I saw the equivalence in various places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew).

I think I have to use Factory.StartNew() in my case as I want to plug in my own TaskScheduler.

So to summ up, it seems that:

```
Task.Run(action)
```

Is strictly equivalent to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

But, I ran a few tests with a simple SerialQueue grabbed [from Microsoft's samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples).

Here is the simple code:

```
/// <summary>Represents a queue of tasks to be started and executed serially.</summary>
public class SerialTaskQueue
{
    /// <summary>The ordered queue of tasks to be executed. Also serves as a lock protecting all shared state.</summary>
    private Queue<object> _tasks = new Queue<object>();
    /// <summary>The task currently executing, or null if there is none.</summary>
    private Task _taskInFlight;

    /// <summary>Enqueues the task to be processed serially and in order.</summary>
    /// <param name="taskGenerator">The function that generates a non-started task.</param>
    public void Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator) { EnqueueInternal(taskGenerator); }

    /// <summary>Enqueues the task to be processed serially and in order.</summary>
    /// <param name="taskOrFunction">The task or functino that generates a task.</param>
    /// <remarks>The task must not be started and must only be started by this instance.</remarks>
    private void EnqueueInternal(object taskOrFunction)
    {
        // Validate the task
        if (taskOrFunction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
        lock (_tasks)
        {
            // If there is currently no task in flight, we'll start this one
            if (_taskInFlight == null) StartTask_CallUnderLock(taskOrFunction);
            // Otherwise, just queue the task to be started later
            else _tasks.Enqueue(taskOrFunction);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Starts the provided task (or function that returns a task).</summary>
    /// <param name="nextItem">The next task or function that returns a task.</param>
    private void StartTask_CallUnderLock(object nextItem)
    {
        Task next = nextItem as Task;
        if (next == null) next = ((Func<Task>)nextItem)();

        if (next.Status == TaskStatus.Created) next.Start();

        _taskInFlight = next;
        next.ContinueWith(OnTaskCompletion);
    }


    /// <summary>Called when a Task completes to potentially start the next in the queue.</summary>
    /// <param name="ignored">The task that completed.</param>
    private void OnTaskCompletion(Task ignored)
    {
        lock (_tasks)
        {
            // The task completed, so nothing is currently in flight.
            // If there are any tasks in the queue, start the next one.
            _taskInFlight = null;
            if (_tasks.Count > 0) StartTask_CallUnderLock(_tasks.Dequeue());
        }
    }
}
```

And now here is my code of some simulated composed task (including await/continuation).

```
    public static async Task SimulateTaskSequence(int taskId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task{0} - Start working 1sec (ManagedThreadId={1} IsThreadPoolThread={2})", taskId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        Console.WriteLine("Task{0} - Zzz 1st 1sec (ManagedThreadId={1} IsThreadPoolThread={2})", taskId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
        await Task.Delay(200);

        Console.WriteLine("Task{0} - Done (ManagedThreadId={1} IsThreadPoolThread={2})", taskId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    }
```

**Test1:** using the queue with Task.Run():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting test program (ManagedThreadId={Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} IsThreadPoolThread={Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread})");

    SerialTaskQueue co_pQueue = new SerialTaskQueue();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var local = i;
        co_pQueue.Enqueue(() => Task.Run(() => { return SimulateTaskSequence(local); }));
    }
}
```

And the result is correct, the queue is processed in the expected order (achieve Task0 before switching to Task1).

> Starting test program (ManagedThreadId=1 IsThreadPoolThread=False)
>   Task0 - Start working 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task0 - Zzz 1st 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task0 - Done (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task1 - Start working 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task1 - Zzz 1st 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task1 - Done (ManagedThreadId=8 IsThreadPoolThread=True)

**Test 2:** just using Factory.StartNew with its perfect equivalence:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting test program (ManagedThreadId={Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} IsThreadPoolThread={Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread})");

    SerialTaskQueue co_pQueue = new SerialTaskQueue();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var local = i;
        co_pQueue.Enqueue(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return SimulateTaskSequence(local); }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default));
    }
}
```

But this time I get the following output:

> Starting test program (ManagedThreadId=1 IsThreadPoolThread=False)
>   Task0 - Start working 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task0 - Zzz 1st 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task1 - Start working 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True) **WHAT?**
>   Task1 - Zzz 1st 1sec (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task0 - Done (ManagedThreadId=9 IsThreadPoolThread=True)
>   Task1 - Done (ManagedThreadId=5 IsThreadPoolThread=True)

I don't get the difference. Why is the behavior different? I thought it was equivalent?! (remember, the step after is plugging in my own scheduler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type from the task factory is `Task <Task>`, the return type of Task.Run is just `Task`.

You need to unwrap the inner task with the factory so that your `ConinueWith` in the queue code is running the continuation on the inner task instead of the outer task.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting test program (ManagedThreadId={Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} IsThreadPoolThread={Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread})");

    SerialTaskQueue co_pQueue = new SerialTaskQueue();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var local = i;
        co_pQueue.Enqueue(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return SimulateTaskSequence(local); }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap());
    }
}
```

Task.Run has a overload that accepts a `Func<Task>` that does this for you. If you declared the delegate in the Task.Run as a `Func<object>` you would see the same behavior from the Task.Run.

Comment: BTW: Is there any reason why the StartNew does not support the Func<Task> by design ?

Comment: @Christophe Because the ability to unwrap a task was only needed because async/await was added to .net and StartNew it is older than that.