# Does a method has to be async when invoked inside an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Lets say I have a method defined as follows:

```
public async Task CreateUser()
{
   await GetUserDetails();
   GetUserOrder();
}

private void GetUserDetails() {

private void GetUserOrder() {
```

Does the method `GetUserDetails();` and `GetUserOrder()` have to be `async` as well to avoid UI blocking ?

I cannot `await` the `GetUserDetails()` method since it is not async. How can I achieve this in c# ? I want to ensure all these methods are invoked step by step.

Comment: You really should never make a void method async unless its an event.  You really need to provide more detail here, `async/await` is not some magic words that make everything faster, we need to know context

Comment: `Task.Add` plus `Task.WaitAll`, you can see a reference here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @maccettura : What if I make `private async Task GetUserDetails();` ?

How can I ensure all my methods are invoked completely sequentially?

Comment: They don't have to be async, but if you want to await them then they should at least return a `Task`.  Ultimately the idea is that somwhere in the call chain your code will `await` an IO bound async method that you don't want to block your thread.  That or you have to spin up a thread for CPU bound code.

Comment: hi i provided you almost all the variation that you cant try as per your requirement ...

Comment: Does `GetUserOrder` ever take more than, say, 30ms to run synchronously? If not, don't worry about it. If yes, then yeah, that's going to block the UI thread for *more than 30ms*.

Comment: @EricLippert : Yeah it takes more than 30ms. How can I prevent this blocking of the UI thread ? What if I create another thread ? Seems legit ?

Comment: Is it taking more than 30ms because it is *doing a complicated computation that maxes out a CPU for more than 30ms*?  If yes, then start a thread. Or is it taking so long because it is waiting for disk, network, or other I/O resource? If it is I/O bound then *do not start a thread*.  Rewrite the method so that it uses asynchronous I/O !

Comment: Its taking more than 30ms as it has to fetch data from the db, make a comparison then add to a list.

Comment: Then **under no circumstances should you start a thread**.  Remember, doing a database lookup is, from the thread's perspective, like you need a recipe and so you order a cookbook from Amazon and wait a week for it to arrive. Here are your choices:  (1) Order the cookbook and sit by your door doing nothing for a week until it arrives. (2) Hire a temp worker to sit by your door doing nothing for a week who then informs you when it arrives. Or (3) make a note to yourself to make dinner when the cookbook arrives, and keep living your life. Which do you choose?

Comment: (1) is what you're doing now -- synchronously waiting for the DB call to return.  (2) is what you're suggesting: hiring an insanely expensive worker to do nothing but wait on your behalf.  (3) is what you should do: **rewrite the method to use asynchronous database IO** and then **await the result**.

Comment: Nice example. I would choose (3).

Comment: `public Task async ObservableCollection<CustomersLoaded> MatchCustomers(ObservableCollection<CustomersLoaded> foundCustomers)
        {
            CustomersLoaded= new ObservableCollection<CustomersLoaded>();

            foundTrucks = new ObservableCollection<Trucks>();

            foundTrucks = await HandleTrucks(foundTrucks);

            TrucksLoaded = await ConstructTrucks(foundTrucks);

            await SavetoLocalDB(CustomersLoaded);

            return TrucksLoaded;
        }`

Is this correct ? wait for each method to execute sequentially and completely?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  Just remember that *await is an operator on tasks, not on calls*, and *await is the sequencing operation*, and you should be fine.

Comment: @EricLippert : Thanks man. I have been struggling a lot with these. The async/ await / Task thing is very confusing sometimes. So I should change the methods signature of all methods that I have awaited to `private async Task HandleTrucks` and so on.

Comment: You're welcome. The thing about async is that it tends to spread through a program; it's hard to make a program only a little bit asynchronous. The key is to identify the I/O bound operations that are the "leaves" of your blocking operations, asyncify them, and then move the asynchrony up the call chain until it's throughout the program.

Answer (score 7):

The relevant question is in a comment:

> How can I ensure all my methods are invoked completely sequentially?

The fact that you're asking the question indicates that you don't understand what "await" is.  **Await is the sequencing operation on a asynchronous workflows**.  An `await` means *this workflow will not proceed until the awaited task is complete*.  It's an **asynchronous wait**, hence the name `await`.

Consider this question: in a synchronous workflow, what is the sequencing operation?

No, really, give it some thought.

.

.

.

It is `;`.  When you say

```
fResult = foo();
bResult = bar();
qResult = qux();
```

that means that foo has to finish completely before bar can begin.  **That is not true for asynchronous workflows**.  If we have

```
fTask = fooAsync();
bTask = barAsync();
qTask = quxAsync();
```

Then the asynchronous operations can complete in any order. If we say

```
await fooAsync();
await barAsync();
await quxAsync();
```

Then **barAsync will not start until fooAsync's task completes**.  `await` *sequences* the asynchronous workflow.  The difference is that *the thread can continue to do other unrelated work while asynchronously waiting for foo to complete*, which is not true in a synchronous workflow; in a synchronous workflow the thread is already busy computing the foo result, so it can't do other work.

Comment: My question is that I want the async method to be invoked completed in an orderly way. Its imperative that they complete in order.

Answer (score 1):

yes if you want to wait than you have to write `await` for that methods also. because after first await your code agian will be synchronous ..and if UI thread than it will run on it.

1.you code will be , so by this code you code become asynchronous for GetUserORder also. you just have to wrap method in Task construct and return

```
public async Task CreateUser()
{
   await GetUserDetails();
   await Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> GetUserOrder());
}
```

2.or you can do this also

```
public async Task CreateUser()
{
   await  Task.Factory.SartNew(()=>{
           GetUserDetails();
           GetUserOrder(); });
}
```

3.or you can do like this also, in below code will not wait for getuserorder method and excute await one method

```
 public async Task CreateUser()
    {
       Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> GetUserOrder()).ContinueWith((t)=> Console.WriteLine("Completed");
       await GetUserDetails();
    }
```

4.or last one variation, here you start GetUserOrder first and dont wait for it than you call GetUserDetails in async fashion , and if you want to work on GetUserOrder method want to wait just use Wait method.

```
 public async Task CreateUser()
    {
      var task =  Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> GetUserOrder());
       await GetUserDetails();   
       if(!task.IsCompleted)
       task.Wait(); 
    }
```

in your case you can go for 3 and if you want to wait go for 4th one.

---

As you asked me in comment what is difference between Task.Run and statnew method -: for that you can check this SO question : [Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: But I cannot await the method `private Task GetUserDetails();` and I do not want to make this method `async`, as it may not execute some code properly.

Comment: @ExpertGenie - not getting you

Comment: Is `Task.Factory.StartNew` same as `Task.Run()` ?

Comment: @ExpertGenie - its same in terms of starting task but starnew provide more parameter than Task.Run and in multithreading senario StartNew is better than Run method

Comment: Hi @Pranay. Thanks for this insight. I'll test and get back to you.

Comment: Can I in turn run the whole method `CreateUser` in `Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await CreateUser();
                    });`

Comment: @ExpertGenie - yes ....I updated my answer with blog post which explain difference between Run and StartNew have look to that also if you wat...

Comment: @ExpertGenie try Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await CreateUser(); }); read post given in my answer and you will get it

Comment: I have upvote the answer for you bro. Could I please contact your personally ?

Answer (score -1):

You should put await only in front of async methods. To run a synchronous one that you don't want to wait, you can use a new thread from the tread pool:

```
new Thread(() => DoSomething()).Start();
```

or

```
Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> DoSomething());
```

Here is the help page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

Otherwise, your call to `GetUserDetails` will have to finish before you execute the next line.

Comment: Do you mean `await Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> GetUserDetails())` ?

Comment: @ExpertGenie - no its means Task.Factory.SartNew(()=> GetUserDetails()), he is provided old way ...means old threading library

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Both ways should work but I will update the answer.