# How to run 3 subs in parallel and wait until all three of them are done to continue in VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I basically have 3 Subs, I would like them to run together and converge once they finish and continue with the main sub. I can do this in C#, I am having difficulty managing to do this in VB.Net

Basically I am trying to accomplish something like the diagram below.

```
                   |---sub1()---|
Start sub()--------|---sub2()---|---main()----> end sub()
                   |---sub3()---|
```

```
Private Sub Manual_Trades_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim T1 As New Task(AddressOf sub1)
    Dim T2 As New Task(AddressOf sub2)
    Dim T3 As New Task(AddressOf sub3)
    T1.Start()
    T2.Start()
    T3.Start()
    Task.WaitAll(T1, T2, T3)
End Sub
```

```
Sub sub1()
    'Do something that takes time
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    'Do something that takes time
End Sub

Sub sub3()
    'Do something that takes time
End Sub
```

Comment: I think Thread.Sleep doesn't work well with task, you should be using [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads). Not 100% sure of that.

Comment: @the_lotus yeah I just got rid of that to clarify the question properly

Comment: What would be different from the c# code?

Comment: What's wrong with the `WaitAll()` you have now?

Comment: I am not sure, for some reason my code runs faster when I run it Synchronously. So I assumed maybe I did something wrong here, used an improper method thus the code snippet. My code is accessing the SQL server to fetch some data to fill up a datatable tho.

Comment: @Adas parallel does not always mean faster. There can be limit when they try to access shared resources or limited by hardware capability.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first sample. You could try using Task.Run instead. [Seems like it's the suggested method of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew).

```
Sub sub1()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("1")
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Console.WriteLine("2")
End Sub

Sub sub3()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Console.WriteLine("3")
End Sub

Sub RunAllAndWait()

    Dim T1 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf sub1)
    Dim T2 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf sub2)
    Dim T3 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf sub3)

    Task.WaitAll({T1, T2, T3})

End Sub
```

Comment: When I do this, it says Run is not a member of Task, when i switch run with start, it says addressOf cannot be converted to taskscheduler because taskscheduler is not a delegate type