# Call a non static method in Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, task

I need to call a non static method `_methodY` in another class `_classX` every time I execute `Task.Factory.StartNew` in class _classA`. I don't want to instantiate a new`classX`every time. Is there a way where I can use the same instantiated`classX`whenever I call`Task.Factory.startNew`from`_classA`

Here is the code:

```
public void _classA
{          
    public void method
    {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(
           () => _classX._methodY(), 
           token1, 
           TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
           TaskScheduler.Default);
    }    
}

public void _classX()
{
     public void _methodY()
     {    
     }
}
```

I can't change `classX` nor `_methodY` to `static`. Do I need to implement singleton?

Comment: use singleton instance and also use `Task.Run`

Comment: Why not Task.StartNew? I want to run my method in a new thread every time I call it

Comment: `Task.Run` will do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew

Comment: How can I implement a threadsafe singleton? So I need to use locks?

Comment: @Tinyteety that's already available through the [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8) class. The initialization code is guaranteed to run only once the first time it's accessed, no matter how many threads call it. You can create a `static readonly Lazy<Whatever>` and use it, but a better option would be to *NOT* use a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling an instance method requires an instance.  You can pass one in, create a new one each time, or create a singleton.

Here is a code sample based on yours that creates and uses a singleton.  The static variable `_singletonX` is instantiated on first use and will contain an instance of `ClassX`.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWorkspace
{

    public class ClassA
    {
        private static readonly ClassX _singletonX = new ClassX();

        public void MyMethod()
        {
            var token1 = new CancellationToken();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _singletonX.MethodY(), token1, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

        }
    }

    public class ClassX
    {
        public void MethodY()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I pass parameters to classx ?

Comment: Yes, but it is tricky.  Because `_singletonX` is a static variable, it is instantiated before the instance of ClassA is created.  You can pass constant parameters or call static functions to get parameter values.  If you delay the construction of your ClassX singleton until after your instance of ClassA is created, you have more flexibility over the parameters, but you lose the guaranteed thread-safety of the static initializer.