# Calculate folder size with multithreading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm creating WPF application to calculate size of directory.
It is necessary that the data on the size of the folders and their contents be displayed in runtime.
How can I use recursion multithreading?
I tried to use the context of synchronization with tasks, but it did not improve performance.

```
public Node GetFolderInfo(Node node)
        {           
            context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            var tscan = new Task(() => ScanStart(node, context));
            tscan.Start();           
            return node;            
        }

private void ScanStart(Node node, SynchronizationContext uiContext)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Thread id = {Task.CurrentId}");
            uiContext.Post(Scan, node);
        }

public void Scan(object nodeObject)
        {
            var node = nodeObject as Node;            

            try
            {
                foreach (var folderPath in Directory.GetDirectories(node.FullName))
                {
                    var folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
                    var newNode = new Node(folder.Name, folder.FullName, TypeNode.Folder, 0, node);
                    node.CountFolders++;
                    node.Children.Add(newNode);
                    var tscan = new Task(() => ScanStart(newNode, context));
                    tscan.Start();
                    //node.Size += newNode.Size;
                    //node.CountFolders += newNode.CountFolders;
                    //node.CountFiles += newNode.CountFiles;
                }

                foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(node.FullName))
                {
                    var file = new FileInfo(filePath);                    
                    var newNode = new Node(file.Name, file.FullName, TypeNode.File, file.Length, (Node)nodeObject);
                    node.CountFiles++;
                    node.Children.Add(newNode);
                    node.Size += newNode.Size;                   
                }                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }            
        }
```

Comment: You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29693430/1136211. Use `await Task.Run(...)` and declare your methods as `async Task ...` or `async Task<Node> ...` and await their calls.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you have a mechanical HDD, the latency of the head might be higher than the benefit obtained by many cores involved.

Comment: Also note that GetDirectories and GetFiles return potentially large arrays, while EnumerateDirectories and EnumerateFiles won't.

Comment: @MarioVernari, It's a bit more complicated than just "seek time" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics), but yes! If the hard drive performance is the bottleneck, then adding more threads won't make it go any faster.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sure it's more complicated. I'm even closer with the Clemens comment, and threads and enumerations make the life harder. All that reasons to think twice before use threads.