# C#: Running an async lambda using Task.Run() / new Task() / Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I'm well aware (thanks to Stephen Toub) that constructing a task with `new Task(...)` is generally not recommended and would normally prefer to use `Task.Run`, but what is the difference between the three approaches below when passing an async lambda as the task to run? I came across something similar to this in production code, so the code below is a highly contrived and simple example.

When passing an async lambda as a task to `Task.Factory.StartNew` and to `new Task(...)` (followed by `Task.Start`), even though we wait for the returned task the lambda does not finish. However, it does when using `Task.Run` - what's the difference here?

(and Stephen Toub states that `Task.Run` is exactly equivalent to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeTask
                      CancellationToken.None, 
                      TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
                      TaskScheduler.Default);
```

See
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace TaskDelay
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly long t0 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} Starting t1");
            var t1 = new Task(async () => await F1(5000, "Task 1"));
            t1.Start();
            t1.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} Starting t2");

            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await F1(5000, "Task 2"), 
                                  CancellationToken.None, 
                                  TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
                                  TaskScheduler.Default);
            t2.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} Starting t3");
            var t3 = Task.Run(async () => await F1(2000, "Task 3"));
            t3.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} State of {nameof(t1)} is {t1.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} State of {nameof(t2)} is {t2.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{Time} State of {nameof(t3)} is {t3.Status}");
        }


        private static async Task F1(int delay, string taskName)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{Time} Started to run F1 for {taskName}");
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{Time} Finished running F1 for {taskName}");
        }
        private static string Time => $"{(int)((DateTime.Now.Ticks - t0) / 10_000),5} ms:";
    }
}
```

And the output is

[image]

Notice we never see "Finished running F1 for Task 1" or "Finished running F1 for Task 2".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: @shingo - no it doesn't. That question is asking why there are several methods to do apparently the same thing. My question is pointing out differences between at least two of the methods and asking why this is.

Comment: *"`Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeTask`"* -- I would suggest to rename the `SomeTask` to `SomeAsyncMethod` or `SomeAsyncDelegate`. A `Task` is not a method!

Comment: Yes it does, you just don't fully comprehend it. And you should also read the links in the answer, [link this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/).

Comment: @JHBonarius the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew) is not a duplicate of this question. The linked question deals with synchronous delegates. This question deals with asynchronous delegates.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias but the accepted answer has the same link you post in your answer below. So the answer is there

Comment: @JHBonarius just because the accepted answer in the other question contains a hint that is useful for answering this question, a hint that is borderline off-topic for the other question, does not make the two questions duplicates IMHO. If you want check out [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417477#417477) meta guidance. Notice the "apples-to-apples" reference.

Comment: `Stephen Toub states that Task.Run is exactly equivalent to` - he states that those are exactly equivalent _when passing an `Action`_. But your code doesn't pass an `Action` (it's passing a `Func<Task>`), so they're _not_ equivalent in your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var t1 = new Task(async () => 
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

If you check the type of the `t1` and `t2` in the Visual Studio, you'll see that they are both `Task<Task>`. This is a `Task` whose [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) is another `Task`. The outer `Task` represent the launching of the async operation, and the inner `Task` represents the completion of the async operation. When the outer `Task` completes, it means that the delegate that creates the inner `Task` has just completed, and so the inner `Task` has just been created. The creation of the inner `Task` happens on a `ThreadPool` thread (by default), so it happens asynchronously in regard to the current thread.

So you have two tasks to wait:

```
t1.Wait();
t1.Result.Wait();
```

Getting the `t1.Result` is blocking. It has the same effect with the `t1.Wait()`. So the first line `t1.Wait();` is not really needed. The second line `t1.Result.Wait();` waits both tasks by itself.

It is possible to do a single `Wait`, if you combine the two tasks to one with the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) method:

```
t1.Unwrap().Wait();
```

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method differs from the other two, because it is equipped with overloads that accept async delegates. These overloads are doing the `Unwrap` automatically, and so they return a `Task`, not a `Task<Task>`. For more details, check out this article: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) by Stephen Toub.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid inner/outer task problem explained by Theodor and to ensure you await the right task (rather than its wrapper task), you can:

1. start the work directly, if you want to start the task immediately and just wait for it later:

   ```
   var t1 = F1(5000, "Task 1"); // no 'await', starts the work

   ... other work

   await t1;
   ```

   (but be aware that the non-async work in F1 will be executed before we return from F1, and this doesn't work with fake async methods)
2. use an async lambda, if you don't want to start the task immediately:

   ```
   Func<Task<int>> f = async () => await WorkAsync(); // no work is started

   var result = await f(); // *Starts* and waits
   ```