# I used "lock" in the "task it doesn't work and race condition occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I used **"lock"** in the **"task"** it **doesn't work and race condition occurred**

I have defined a Counter, which should eventually return 0, because a Method increases the value of the Counter and a Method decreases it.

**And when I use Thread it is not a problem. This problem occurs when I use Task**

I use **lock** and **monitor** But it did not work again and gave the same result as before

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class LockDemo
    {
        private readonly static object _lock = new object();
        private static int _count = 0;
        public void Main()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(new Task(() => IncrementCounter()));
                tasks.Add(new Task(() => DecrementCounter()));
            }

            foreach (var item in tasks)
            {
                item.Start();
            }
        }
        void IncrementCounter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wait for opening lock...");
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                Console.WriteLine("enter the critical section");
                _count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + _count);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("exit critical section");
        }
        void DecrementCounter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wait for opening lock...");
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("enter the critical section");
                _count -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + _count);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("exit critical section");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your expected behavior in code 1? What is your expected behavior on code 2? Please insert code as text, not only as image.

Comment: expected behavior should return 0 and nothing else

Comment: I understand the last counter value should be 0, but your images doesn't show anything different. Intermediate values could be anything from -1000 to 1000, right?

Comment: You assume the tasks will run in order you call `Task.Run`, but that's not (always) true, otherwise that would be regular sequential execution.

Comment: If you use `lock` inside a task, you're doing something wrong. Tasks aren't threads anyway, they're a *promise* that something will complete in the future. They may not even use a thread to run. When they run on threads, they use threads from a threadpool. Even though you start 2000 tasks these won't run on 2000 threads. There's no good reason to use `Thread.Start`

Comment: BTW the question's code never waits for the tasks to complete and will exit immediately. I suspect the only reason that anything is printed is that the code executes in a debugger. In a Release build, the application could easily exit without printing anything. `when I use Thread it is not a problem.` I doubt it, unless the code  explicitly calls Thread.Join. The problems would be the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It was great, thank you. I was not aware of how ThreadPool works

Answer (score 3):

You're creating two thousand tasks: 1,000 increment and 1,000 decrement. Even though you're starting the tasks in a specific order, there's no guarantee they will execute in that order because they're running asynchronously. Its possible for two decrements to happen, and then a single increment, etc. - which is likely what you're seeing here.

Also, it is not recommended to use Task.Start

[Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/

Comment: it's true ! But I use lock(monitor), so I expect that two threads should not be able to do work at the same time