# Queuing async tasks and passing back result to caller

Tags: c#, async-await, queue, task, .net-6.0

In my app I have a single Client class responsible to do communication via TCP/IP and I have several async Processes posting "work" to the Client class. What I am trying to achieve is to manage a queue of "work", where the items from the queue are processed continuously  but in such a way that only one item is processed at a time and when the item has been processed I need to pass back it's result to the caller.

I am looking for some guidelines.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: probably tasks are different?

Comment: What is the type of the work? Is it synchronous or asynchronous? (`Action` or `Func<Task>`?)

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but it has some similarities: [Task sequencing and re-entracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424084/task-sequencing-and-re-entracy)

Comment: Thx @Theodor Zoulias this is what I wanted! Works fine in my case too.