# Self continuing Task using ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a task that needs to run periodically. My first implementation was like:

```
public static void CheckTask(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
   do
   {
      // Do some processing
      Console.WriteLine("Processing");

      // Sleep awhile and wait for cancellation
      // If not cancelled, repeat
   } while (!tokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1500));

   Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
}
```

This task is started like so:

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task task = null;
task = new Task((x)=> {
    CheckTask(tokenSource);
    //CheckTask2(t, (object)tokenSource);
}, tokenSource.Token);
task.Start();
```

Then I thought instead of looping in the task, why not reschedule it using ContinueWith? My next implementation was like this:

```
public static void CheckTask2(Task task, object objParam)
{
   CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = (CancellationTokenSource)objParam;
   // Do some processing
   Console.WriteLine("Processing");
   // Sleep awhile and wait for cancellation
   if(tokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1500))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Cancel requested");
      return;
   }
   // Reschedule
   task.ContinueWith(CheckTask2, tokenSource);
}
```

The second implementation is much easier to read and write and my tests showed no difference but I still wonder if there are drawbacks for a task to ContinueWith itself?

Comment: I think this question is more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. That being said, it seems like the accepted pattern (see [this question on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3f4f460-7d35-4406-b427-9c77bbbe6b55/repeating-tasks?forum=tpldataflow) ); see also [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999827/a-pattern-for-self-cancelling-and-restarting-task) for a cancellation pattern using await and async, which could or could not be relevant :p

Comment: There are associated startup costs with creating a Task (which `ContinueWith` is doing), but those should be negligible. If it works for you and makes the code cleaner: go ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I still wonder if there are drawbacks for a task to ContinueWith
>   itself?

Frankly, i find your code less readable with the continuation attached (but that is only flavor based). The only drawback i see is the fact that you use a `WaitHandle` on the token which forces you now to [dispose your `CancellationToken` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Accessing this property causes a WaitHandle to be instantiated. It is
>   preferable to only use this property when necessary, and to then
>   dispose the associated CancellationTokenSource instance at the
>   earliest opportunity (disposing the source will dispose of this
>   allocated handle). The handle should not be closed or disposed
>   directly.

Instead, I find the pattern with a `Task.Delay` more clean and readable:

```
public static async Task CheckTask(CancellationToken token)
{
   do
   {
      // Do some processing
      Console.WriteLine("Processing");

      await Task.Delay(1500, token);
   } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);

   Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
}
```

And then when you want to stop your `Task`, cancel its via `CancellationTokenSource`.